# Can i make a nested object within an array?

Tags: typescript, postgresql

So i'm wanting to do the below.

```
let listOne: any = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
let details: any;

// prior to this i had a loop running and 'row' was the response that would output the items 
// in the listOne array

const query_for_details = `SELECT column1 FROM tableName WHERE itemId = '${row}'`;
details = await client.query(query_for_details).then((res: any) => res.rows
console.log(details)
// Output for each item in the listOne array {name1: value1, name2: value2, name3:value3}
```

now what im wanting to do is once the output for the query is made i want to then add the above into a new variable like in the below section

```
let listOneDetails: any = [{'item1': {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3':'value3'}},
{'item2': {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3':'value3'}},
{'item3': {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3':'value3'}}]
```

i've read about using a reducer, but I don't feel that quite works as a solution for my situation. All assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `client`, which library are you using? Also your `query_for_details` declaration has syntax errors.

Comment: Please post the full code, including the loop and prior query.

Comment: Please share your table definition and the example data as SQL.

Comment: client is the connection i established and then later close by doing client.release(). I can't really post all the code which is why i posted the above.@Bergi. ill edit the code i just realized the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce, but I'll give you the correct algorithmic answer too.

You need to avoid doing 1 query per row, (infamous N+1 anti-pattern). So unless there're too many rows, you can fetch all in one query just by using a `where itemId IN (<ids array>)`

Then, and to answer your question, once you have all your rows, you need to create an index so you can join rows with items efficiently (N*Log(N)). You can use a library (lodash's indexBy), or do it in 3 lines like this:

```
const detailsById = {};
res.rows.forEach(row => detailsById[row.itemId] = row); 
// where row.itemId is what it'd link it to the list One items
```

Then, to do the join, use a reduce if you want like this:

```
listOne.reduce((acc, itemId) => { acc[itemId] = detailsById[itemId]; return acc;} , {});
```